# How to create int-file:outbound gateway via Java configuration

Tags: java, spring-integration

I am trying to convert `file:outbound-gateway` configuration in XML to Java config, but can't find the correct API.

XML:

```
<file:outbound-gateway directory="file:myDir"
    request-channel="inFiles" auto-create-directory="true"
    delete-source-files="true" reply-channel="outFiles">
</file:outbound-gateway>
```

This is what I have so far on Java configuration. Not sure how to set `request-channel` and `reply-channel`:

```
@Bean
public MessageHandler fileOutBoundGateway() {
    FileWritingMessageHandler gateway = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File("myDir"));
    gateway.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
    gateway.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);

    // FIXME need to set request and reply channel
    return gateway;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `request-channel` (`inputChannel`) is an option of the `endpoint`. In your case you have only `channel` and `MessageHandler`, but there is still no `endpoint`.

Only what you need is `service-activator`:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "input")
public MessageHandler fileOutBoundGateway() {
    FileWritingMessageHandler gateway = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File("myDir"));
    gateway.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
    gateway.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    gateway.setOutputChannel(outputChannel());
    return gateway;
}
```

Please, find more info in the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/files.html#_configuring_with_java_configuration_7).
Also pay attention, please, to the [Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl).

Comment: Thanks. I also need reply-channel. Which one should I use: @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "in", outputChannel = "out") or @Gateway(request-channel = "in", reply-channel = "out")

Comment: No, and no. Please, read this http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations carefully. I've shown you already that you should use `gateway.setOutputChannel()`. It is `reply-channel` from the XML DSL, but that doesn't matter that the target `MessageHandler` will have the same option.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It makes sense now.